# Filter a tuple list of types given a template template predicate

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14, template-meta-programming

I was going to ask a question, but have found an answer on my own while writing it.
The question is how to filter a tuple given a template template predicate without specializing it.

Example usage:

```
    using tuple_list_t = std::tuple<std::string, int, none, double, char, abc, bool>;
    using tuple_found_expected_t = std::tuple<int, double, char, bool>;

    // filtering a tuple 
    using tuple_filtered_t = filter_t<tuple_list_t, std::is_fundamental>;

    static_assert(std::is_same<tuple_filtered_t, tuple_found_expected_t>(), "");
```

If someone have any advices or remarks about the problem, please, write an answer or a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry but your solution seems to me over-complicated. Particularly regarding the SFINAE part (why the `void`?).

What about simply as follows?

```
template <typename, template <typename...> class>
struct filter;

template <typename ... Ts, 
          template <typename...> class Pred>
struct filter<std::tuple<Ts...>, Pred>
 { 
   using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<
      std::conditional_t<Pred<Ts>::value,
                         std::tuple<Ts>,
                         std::tuple<>>>()...));
 };

template <typename Tpl, 
          template <typename...> class Pred>
using filter_t = typename filter<Tpl, Pred>::type;
```

Comment: My code did not compile for some reason without a template typename specialization. Now it does. You version is shorter and simpler indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of a template SFINAE struct to filter an `std::tuple` of types given a SFINAE predicate. So the invocation looks just like using an STL algorithm with an unary predicate.

Example:

```
    using tuple_list_t = std::tuple<std::string, int, none, double, char, abc, bool>;
    using tuple_found_expected_t = std::tuple<int, double, char, bool>;

    // filtering a tuple 
    using tuple_filtered_t = filter_t<tuple_list_t, std::is_fundamental>;

    static_assert(std::is_same<tuple_filtered_t, tuple_found_expected_t>(), "");
```

There were two major problems that I have faced.

1. How to pass a template as a template template parameter without specializing it:
   `eld::filter<tuple, std::is_fundamental>`.   Here `std::is_fundamental` is a template itself and expects to be specialized. But I can't specialize it before the invocation - I need to specialize it later with the types from a tuple.
   Solution is simple. Just have a stub `void` (for example) default specializtion:

```
template <typename Tuple, template <typename> class SFINAEPredicate, typename = void>
```

2. Removing types that yield false with `SFINAEPredicate<T>::value`.
   Now there is a way to use recursive SFINAE template specialization, but it requires a lot of typing and possibly a lot of redundant code generation. The latter is a big concern when compiling in debug, since MinGW will fail with assembler error `file too big` and up to this point I have found no working way to circumvent this problem (optimization pragmas don't do nothing). But that is out of scope of this question/answer.
   The way I did it was with `using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(append_if_t<std::tuple<>, Types, SFINAEPredicate>()...));`
   `append_if_t` returns a tuple, which will be empty in some cases, and then all of them are concatenated in a final tuple with an `std::tuple_cat`.
   So, there are N specializations for `append_if_t` which can be reused by the compiler and no recursive intermediate specializations.

Here is the code:

```
        template<typename Tuple, typename T, template<typename> class /*SFINAEPredicate*/, typename = T>
        struct append_if;

        template<typename T, template<typename> class SFINAEPredicate, typename ... Types>
        struct append_if<std::tuple<Types...>, T, SFINAEPredicate, T>
        {
            using type = typename std::conditional<SFINAEPredicate<T>::value,
                    std::tuple<Types..., T>, std::tuple<Types...>>::type;
        };

        template<typename Tuple, typename T, template<typename> class SFINAEPredicate, typename = T>
        using append_if_t = typename append_if<Tuple, T, SFINAEPredicate>::type;

        // TODO: function to traverse a tuple and find a type (index) that can be used to initialize a POD element
        // pass a template parameter (trait validator) that accepts a type

        // template for find_if in tuple
        template<typename Tuple, template<typename> class /*SFINAEPredicate*/, typename = void>
        struct filter;

        template<template<typename> class SFINAEPredicate, typename ... Types>
        struct filter<std::tuple<Types...>, SFINAEPredicate, void>
        {
            using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(append_if_t<std::tuple<>, Types, SFINAEPredicate>()...));
        };

        template<typename Tuple, template<typename> class SFINAEPredicate, typename = void>
        using filter_t = typename filter<Tuple, SFINAEPredicate>::type;
```